# Typoscript 9.5 render FILES Object like Contentelement

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

i get via CONTENT an Element from the page and want to render the image from this like all other images in the page.
i have installed sms for responsive images but when i render this image via typoscript an normal `<img>` will be outputtet.
how must i change my typoscript to render like in the partial file Media/Rendering/Image?

```
                            20 = FILES
                            20{
                                references {
                                    table = tt_content
                                    fieldName = image
                                    uid.data = field:uid
                                }
                                begin = 0
                                maxItems = 1
                                renderObj = IMAGE
                                renderObj {
                                    file.import.data = file:current:publicUrl
                                    file.width = 1920c
                                    file.treatIdAsReference = 1
                                    stdWrap.outerWrap = |
                                }
                            }
```

thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

As the example you mention is rendered in Fluid, I'd suggest to use Fluid as well. The ViewHelper for responsive images is used in Fluid.
Try to get away from rendering via TypoScript and use Fluid templates.